# Python sched scheduler and reboots

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have read about python `sched` (task scheduler), it works like a cron.

but I have a question :

- lets say if I schedule a function to run after every 2 hours and in the mean time my system gets shut down, then I again restart the system...

Does the scheduler automatically start and run the function after 2 hours? Or do I have to start that again after shutting down the system?

- Does `sched` work like a daemon?

Comment: Did you read the source for `sched`?  It's 135 lines of code.  What part of it was hard to understand?

Comment: i am newbie so couldnt understand. what i want to ask is turbogear says it asmini cron her :http://www.razorvine.net/download/kronos.py. but its using sched. then how can it be cron?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to all three questions is **No**.

sched is different from cron. It takes a generic timer or counter function and a delay function and lets you to schedule a function call after a particular time (an event as defined by your generic timer function).

It won't run after you close your program, unless you maintain state by writing to a file or db. This is complicated and using cron would be better.

sched works on events, but not on background. so, it not is not exactly a deamon, but you can deamonize it running the program in the background using OS facilities.

Comment: thanks senthi. but if you can see  in turbogear, http://docs.turbogears.org/TGScheduler, they have used sched for scheduling. if i keep the scheduled function in the service, will it work even after reboot?

Comment: Kronos and TGScheduler are higher level abstrations to the basic premises of scheduling tasks. The seem to define some concrete time based tasks (like first day of month), so even if the app is restarted those will work, but interval based will not work (because session is not maintained). They fork the running to an another task so that it runs as a process in the background. As I said, they seem to use lot more (OS related, threading and Concrete Events using datetime) than just the sched.

Comment: thanks senthil for reply. I have gone throgh kronos in detail. My question is : even if you fork or create a new thread for a process and work with datetime calculation, how it is possible to continue same scheduling after SYSTEM restart?

Comment: It may not be the same scheduler which is running after the system restar, but a different one with a updated calculation. for e.g you define soemthing to be run on 6th of each month. Because this event is fixed, the scheduler can work after a restart.

Comment: thanks senthil, but how can that event be again triggered in system restart??? once system gets restarted, either we have to run the event again then that scheduler will start over again. how can event will be triggered at system restart?

Comment: Event does not get after the System restart. It is assumed that you ru your Turbogears application again.

Answer (score 0):

and if this is so :
will this also work even after system restart?
answer is : NO then how can turbogear scheduler can run using cronos in cron? scheduled events in turbogear will also be vanished after SYSTEM restart.
PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG.

```
import time
import sched
import datetime
import threading
import calendar
#from datetime import datetime


class test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    def getSec(self):

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "now - ", now
        currentYear = now.year
        currentMonth = now.month
        currentDay = now.day
        currentHour = now.hour
        currentMinute = now.minute
        currentSecond = now.second
        currentMicroseconds = now.microsecond
        command = "python runbackup.py"
        print "command is - ", command

        print "currentMinute - ", currentMinute
        print "currentSecond - ", currentSecond
        # current time
        a = datetime.datetime(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinute, currentSecond, currentMicroseconds)

        last_date_of_current_month = calendar.monthrange(currentYear, currentMonth)[1]
        print "last_date_of_current_month - ", last_date_of_current_month
        b = datetime.datetime(currentYear, currentMonth, int(last_date_of_current_month), 23, 59, 59, 000000)
        #b = datetime.datetime(currentYear, currentMonth, int(29), 18, 29, 00, 000000)
        #print "date time of b is - %s %s " % (18, 29)

        c = b-a
        print "c is - ", c

        time.sleep(1)
        scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        #scheduler.cancel(e1)
        sec = c.seconds
        print "second -  ", sec
        print "scheduler entered."
        e1 = scheduler.enter(sec, 1, self.getSec, ())
        t = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)
        print "thread started."
        print "======================================"
        t.start()

        #scheduler.cancel(e1)
        #print "canceled."

        return True

if __name__=='__main__'  :
    obj = test()
    obj.getSec()
```